# AutoScroll problem when using Left Dock - C# Telerik Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Here is my code:

```
RadScrollablePanel panel = new RadScrollablePanel() { AutoScroll = true, Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
pnlclp.PanelContainer.Controls.Add(panel);
foreach (var date in dates)
    panel.Controls.Add(new ucDetails() { Dock = DockStyle.Left });
```

I'm adding some controls inside a `RadScrollablePanel` and then adding it into a `PanelContainer`.
Everything works great. If I add so many controls inside the `RadScrollablePanel` which is not visible in first look, the scroll bar will be shown as well.

But If I change the `DockStyle.Left` to `DockStyle.Right` in foreach loop, after loading the controls, it will not show the scroll bar and it is strange and I can not find any reason or solution to solve this issue.

I even try to change the `RightToLeft` property of `RadScrollablePanel`. but no success :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Following the provided information, I have prepared a sample project to test the behaior in RadScrollablePanel.
I have logged it in our feedback portal by creating a public thread. You can track its progress, subscribe for status changes and add your comments on the following link: https://feedback.telerik.com/winforms/1453253-radscrollablepanel-missing-scrollbar-when-there-is-no-enough-space-to-display-the-content-controls

I hope this information helps.

Comment: it is a very high-level BUG for a scrollable panel which its mission is to show scroll in certain times. Then when I look inside the link you provided, it is labeled as an unplanned bug!!! do you think such tag is right? How long should I wait for a fix?

Comment: The encountered problem is a straight consequence of the default behavior of the standard WinForms Panel. If you try the same scenario with a standard Panel you will end up with the same problem - the horizontal scrollBar is not shown, even though the form is being resized.
When designing the RadScrollablePanel our team decided to mimic the behavior of standard WinForms Panel. Unfortunately, along with all its features, RadScrollablePanel has also inherited Panel's problems.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem of the standard Microsoft WinForms Panel, I can suggest docking all the UserControls to the Left and use an empty Panel that occupies all the available space on the left of the form, so exactly the same behavior as all UserControls are docked to the Right. When the size of the form is changed adjust the width of the empty panel. The described approach is illustrated with the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl1[] userControls;
    RadScrollablePanel parentPanel;
    Panel spacePanel;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new Telerik.WinControls.RadControlSpy.RadControlSpyForm().Show();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.parentPanel = new RadScrollablePanel();
        this.parentPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        this.parentPanel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        this.Controls.Add(this.parentPanel);
        this.parentPanel.AutoScroll = true;

        int count = 10;
        this.userControls = new UserControl1[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.userControls[i] =
                new UserControl1()
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Left,
                    BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)(i + 50))
                };

            this.parentPanel.Controls.Add(this.userControls[i]);
        }

        this.spacePanel = new Panel();
        this.spacePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        this.parentPanel.Controls.Add(this.spacePanel);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        if (this.spacePanel != null)
        {
            int lastPanelWidth = this.parentPanel.Width;
            foreach (Control control in this.parentPanel.PanelContainer.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Dock == DockStyle.Left && control != this.spacePanel)
                {
                    lastPanelWidth -= control.Width;
                }
            }

            if (lastPanelWidth < 0)
            {
                lastPanelWidth = 0;
            }

            this.spacePanel.Width = lastPanelWidth;
        }
    }
}
```